# Ratchet framework: needing to click logout link twice

Tags: php, ratchet

I just started using Ratchet (http://maker.github.io/ratchet/) and it's great. However, a big issue I'm having is that the user has to click the logout button (which is actually an anchor `<a>`) twice in order for the logout to actually occur.

I'm intending this as an app to be saved to the iPhone homescreen, where it can be launched as a fullscreen webapp. Normally, sessions aren't maintained when such a web app is closed (it's sandboxed as opposed to regular Safari). I'm 99% certain that this click-twice-to-logout issue is because I am using not only a PHP session but also a cookie in order to make it so that the user will remain logged in after closing the full screen web app (as per the second answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998900/maintain-php-session-in-web-app-on-iphone)).

My logout script is as follows:

```
// logout.php

<?php

session_start();

setcookie(session_name(),"",time()-3600);
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
header('Location: /');

?>
```

I thought this issue might have something to do with Ratchet's `push.js`, but even if I set the logout link with `data-ignore="push"`, the current page just reopens in Safari (which is annoying on its own, because if the user has it saved to their home screen, I want it to run only within that full screen interface), and I still have to tap logout once more.

The issue also does not appear to be a problem of running it as a full screen web app, as I have the same issue accessing it via Safari.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I solved the issue. From that link I had posted before, I had inserted the following code into all of my main PHP pages:

```
$cookieLifetime = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60; // A year in seconds
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$cookieLifetime);
```

I don't fully understand this, but I get that it's basically creating a cookie which allows the session to be maintained even when the app is run in iOS's sandboxed full-screen web app mode. I was able to fix the issue by *removing* this code from my `login.php` script while keeping it on every other page of my app. `logout.php` remains as before. Now, my saved-to-home-screen full screen web app will keep the user logged in, even if the iPhone is restarted. They are also able to logout with a single tap of the logout button instead of twice.